# Boats and Streams:::

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Speed of a swimmer when moving in the direction perpendicular to the
>   direction of the current is 16km/h,speed of the current is 3km/h,so
>   the speed of the swimmer against the current will be

```
In this Question swimmer moving in the direction perpendicular to the direction,it denotes upstream or Downstream
```

If downstream means relative speed will be we can add the swimmer speed  and  current speed and upstream  means relative speed will be we can subtract the swimmer speed  and  current speed

**`But in this question I cannot proceed further , can anyone explain and solve the answer please`**

**Perpendicular direction means denotes which direction ?**

Comment: Is that the exact phrasing of the original question?

Comment: yes @DavidQuinn this is exact Question

Comment: @DavidQuinn In book how they answered means speed of swimmer =16-3 = 13km/hr, speed of swimmer against current will be 13-3 = 10km/hr, How they solved can you explain please

Comment: It would seem there is something wrong with the question and it should not say "perpendicular to the direction"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy -

Speed in perpendicular directionhere means downstream speed.

If swimmer is moving at speed of 16 kmph in downstream. It means his speed is increased by current. And increase in speed is equal to current speed. So if you subtract current speed from downstream speed. You get swimmer speed in still water. So we have 16-3=13 kmph as speed of swimmer.

As current speed is 3 kmph. Suppose you pick swimmer from still water and drop against current to swim. As we know it's hard to swim against current. So speed decrease. And decrease in speed is equal to current speed.

We have 13-3=10 kmph.

Answer (score 1):

Your velocity triangle will be a right-angled triangle with the speed of the swimmer relative to the water as the hypotenuse. So use Pythagoras and get $$\sqrt{16^2+3^2}=...$$

Comment: How the swimmer can swim perpendicular direction @David  Quinn,I am not able to get it guide me full answer

Comment: I understand that the swimmer is managing to swim straight across the river (so his velocity relative to the riverbank is perpendicular to the current downstream) but in order not to be swept downstream, he must aim slightly upstream, such that the velocity triangle is right-angled

Comment: after finding relative velocity i got 16.27 that is the answer @David Quinn

Comment: actually $16.2788206...$ so $16.28$ (2dp)

Comment: so Answer is 16.28,please upvote my question @David Quinn,I have understand

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: but the original answer is 10 , please guide me how @David Quninn,we are doing some mistake i think so